# Can't position Modal Popup

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I am trying to open a modal pop up in response to click on an image. The modal pop up will display a zoomed in version of the image. It keeps displaying the pop up in the center of the screen no matter what I do to position it differently. I tried to put the update panel inside a div, no change. For the images, I have a javascript onclick event:

```
onclick = "fnZoomImage(this.src)"
```

The js functions are:

```
function fnZoomImage(imageUrl) {
    var imgZoom = document.getElementById("imgZoom");
    imgZoom.src = imageUrl.replace("WebVersion/", "");
    imgZoom.style.display = "block";
    var modalpopup = $find('mpeZoom'); 
    modalpopup.show();
    return false;
}

function HideImage() {
    var imgZoom = document.getElementById("imgZoom");
    imgZoom.style.display = "none";
    var modalpopup = $find('mpeZoom'); 
    modalpopup.hide();
}
```

Pop up extender is:

```
<div style="position:fixed;top:100;left:200;">
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upnlZoom" RenderMode="Inline">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlZoom" style="position:fixed;top:100;left:200;border:solid 2px navy;display:none;">
            <img id="imgZoom" style="display: none;" />
            <input type="button" id="btnClose" value="Close" onclick="HideImage()" style="width:75px;" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeZoom" BehaviorID="mpeZoom" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnFake" BackgroundCssClass="backgrondModal" DropShadow="true" PopupControlID="pnlZoom" PopupDragHandleControlID="pnlZoom" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnFake" Style="display:none" /> 
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

I am trying to position the popup at left:200px,top:100px.

Comment: Don't you want position:absolute instead of fixed on the containing <div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your left and top position for the popup through the `set_X` and `set_Y` properties like below and remove the style (position, left and top) you set for the panel `pnlZoom` and the div above the Update Panel.

```
modalpopup.set_X(200);
modalpopup.set_Y(100);
modalpopup.show();
```

**UPDATE 1:** Based on you comment, if you want to display the modal popup relative to the position of the control triggering the click then do as follows. You can use [Sys.UI.DomElement.getLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397695(v=vs.100).aspx) method to get the offset of the control.

Change your onclick to pass `this` to reference the img/button object

```
 onclick = "fnZoomImage(this, this.src)"
```

and your `fnZoomImage` function will become

```
function fnZoomImage(obj, imageUrl) {
     .....
     .....
     var location = Sys.UI.DomElement.getLocation(obj);
     var xPos = location.x;
     var yPos = location.y;

     xPos = xPos - 200; // adjust the value accordingly
     yPos = yPos + obj.offsetHeight; 

     modalpopup.set_X(xPos);
     modalpopup.set_Y(yPos);
     modalpopup.show();
     .....
     .....
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dennis. That did it. I guess this is with respect to screen and not the web page (web page does NOT take up entire screen size). If that's the case, is it possible to set the coordinates wrt web page coordinates?

Comment: Glad it works.. You can even show the popup relative to the position of the button clicked (popup will be shown next to the button click and not always at a fixed center position). Let me know if you need the code for this. I think you should be able to get the page's coordinates too.

Comment: Thank you Dennis. Appreciate the help. I would love to have the code to show the pop up next to click position. Thanks.

Comment: @NoBullMan Edited my answer with the code for the alternate approach.